# How to consume Rest API with complex objects using Httparty and Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, httparty

I am trying to implement call this API method in Ruby https://zferral.com/api-docs/affiliate#aff-create-usage-example which expects this object:

```
{  "affiliate" : {
    "email"           : "john@example.com",
    "send_user_email" : "1" }}
```

Using a Httparty class, I call this:

```
result = self.class.post("/api/#{@apikey}/affiliate/create.xml", :body => {:affiliate => {:email => email}})
```

Unfortunately, the API keeps sending me "Email is required". I have tried to switch to json, I am changed :body with :query, etc...

Anybody could show me how to call the affiliate/create method correctly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You're sending json, but posting it to create.xml --- in rails, this will auto-set the content type to be xml when you post to create.xml

Try posting to `/api/#{@apikey}/affiliate/create.json`

If that doesn't work --- are you following the class design that HTTParty really likes? http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2008/07/29/it-s-an-httparty-and-everyone-is-invited/

Answer (score 2):

This is how I fixed my issue:

```
    url = URI.parse('https://xxxx.zferral.com/api/xxx/affiliate/create.xml')
    http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
    http.use_ssl = true
    http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.path)
    request.body = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><affiliate><email>#{email}</email><send_user_email>0</send_user_email></affiliate>"
    request.content_type = 'text/xml'
    response = http.request(request)
```